# Javascript - Getting wrong size for current iframe in iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the isolation of a bigger problem. I'm working with a parent window which contains an `iframe`.

When I run the following code on my `Android` mobile (tested with Chrome) I get a popup window with `300 , 300` as expected. The same happens on my desktop computer (with whatever browser: Firefox, Chrome, etc).

But when I do the same with `IPhone / Safari` or `IPhone / Chrome`, I get: `700 , 700`.

I need to get: `300 , 300` on my `IPhone` independently of the size I set to `.frame`. In other words, I need the size of the viewport, which is set on the parent window.

If you wanna quickly try what I mean here (`Android or Desktop` vs `iPhone`), you can run the following example, where you will see that on `iPhone`, you get: `700 , 700` where it should be `300, 300`:

```js
var content_iframe = '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
'<html>'+
'<head>'+
'<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" \/>'+
'<meta charset="UTF-8" \/>'+
'<title>IFrame<\/title>'+
'<style type="text\/css">'+
'body, html {'+
' margin: 0;'+
' padding: 0;'+
' overflow: hidden;'+
'}'+
'.frame {'+
' position: absolute;'+
' width: 700px;'+  // I need this to be ignored!
' height: 700px;'+ // I need this to be ignored!
'}'+
'<\/style>'+
'<script type="text\/javascript">'+
'setTimeout(function(){'+
' var width = window.innerWidth;'+
' var height = window.innerHeight;'+
' alert(width + " , " + height);'+
'}, 500);'+
'<\/script>'+
'<\/head>'+
'<body>'+
' <div class="frame"><\/div>'+
'<\/body>'+
'<\/html>';
document.getElementById('test_iframe').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(content_iframe);
```

```css
iframe {
    /* this is what I need to be output */
 border: none;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #e9f1ff;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="test_iframe"></iframe>
```

Just, in case you cannot run the above example on your `iPhone` right here with the built-in runner, you can try the `JSFiddle` runner here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ssbo3dh8/

Could you provide me back a`JSFiddle` with a working code for `iPhone`, based on my code above?, I mean, just doing the necessary modifications?

Any idea on how to get this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You should test body.innerWidth

Comment: getting: `ReferenceError: body is not defined`

Comment: document.querySelector('body').innerWidth

Answer (score 0):

**Check again** this code :

```
var content_iframe = '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
'<html>'+ 
'<head>'+
'<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" \/>'+ 
'<meta charset="UTF-8" \/>'+
'<title>IFrame<\/title>'+
'<style type="text\/css">'+
'body, html {'+
'   margin: 0;'+ 
'   padding: 0;'+ 
'   overflow: hidden;'+ 
'}'+ 
'.frame {'+ 
'   position: absolute;'+ 
'   width: 700px;'+  // I need this to be ignored! '    
height: 700px;'+ // I need this to be ignored! '}'+ 
'.main {'+ '    
width: 300px;'+  // I need this to be ignored! '    
height: 300px;'+ // I need this to be ignored! '}'+ 
'<\/style>'+ 
'<script type="text\/javascript">'+ 
'setTimeout(function(){'+ 
'   var width = document.getElementById("main").offsetWidth;'+ '    
var height = document.getElementById("main").offsetHeight;'+ '  
alert(width + 
" , " + 
height);'+ 
'}, 500);'+ 
'<\/script>'+ 
'<\/head>'+ 
'<body>'+ 
'<div id="main" class="main">   <div class="frame"><\/div>  </div>'+ 
'<\/body>'+ 
'<\/html>'; 
document.getElementById('test_iframe').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(content_iframe);
```

HTML

```
<iframe id="test_iframe"></iframe>
```

CSS

```
iframe {
  /* this is what I need to be output */
    border: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #e9f1ff;
}
```

Comment: tried this but got `700 , 700` on my iPhone. `300 , 300` on my desktop, though.

Comment: Check again @DavidSmith

Answer (score 0):

Check your frame body instead of window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
    var width = document.querySelector('body').offsetWidth;
    var height = document.querySelector('body').offsetHeight;
    alert(width + ' , ' + height);
}, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: tried this but got: `700 , 0` on my iPhone, and `300 , 0` on my desktop computer